# Click every button on a page with the same path

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I was experimenting with puppeteer and I had a program that navigates to youtube and logs the URL src and title text and it works fine. The issue is there is a dropdown button on the main youtube page that drops down to display more content and the is multiple of those drop-down buttons across the page what I was trying to do was click them all to extend them and log the URL src. I already have a click eval that clicks on the button but it only clicks on the first one how can I make that eval to click on every button with a similar path on the page and extend them all. A added a loop to iterate on clicking the button but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
async function scrape(url) {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800
  });

  const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();


  await page.goto(url, {
    timeout: 0
  });

  await page.evaluate(_ => {
    window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
  });

  await page.waitFor(5000);
  await page.waitForSelector('#button')
  await page.waitForSelector('#img')
  await navigationPromise;

  var ytTextData;
  for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    const textSelector = 'h3 > a > #video-title'
    const srcSelector = 'ytd-thumbnail > a > yt-img-shadow > #img'
    await page.waitForSelector(textSelector)
    await page.waitForSelector(srcSelector)
    //loop i tried but doesn't work.
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      let elements = document.querySelectorAll('#button-container > #show-more-button > a > #button');
      for (let element of elements) {
        element.click();
      }
    });
    const ytTextData = await page.$$eval(textSelector, elems => elems.map(el => el.textContent).join('\n'))
    const ytSrcData = await page.$$eval(srcSelector, elems => elems.map(el => el.src).join('\n'))
    if (ytTextData && ytSrcData) {
      console.log({
        ytTextData,
        ytSrcData
      })
    }
  }

  await browser.close();

}
```

Comment: Make sure that the page version viewed by the Chromium browser driven by puppeteer sees the same page as you (when you debug in your own browser). Your for...of loop looks correct, it seems there are no other elements for `'#button-container > #show-more-button > a > #button'`. You could check its length in `page.$$eval` to make sure how many "read more" buttons are available within the page. You also said "every button with a similar path", which makes the task a bit more complex, you should be able to define the pattern you want to match then the same loop will work.

Comment: By "define the pattern" you mean calculate the length of the ```page.$$eval``` then apply the loop length times?@theDavidBarton

Comment: No, by the pattern I meant: you wrote that you want to click on buttons with a "similar" path, so maybe they have not identical selectors? (I cannot know, for me only one "read more" is visible on the page). In that case, your for..of loop will iterate an array of elements on a [list of selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors#selector_lists). But it would be good if you could elaborate what you've meant by: "every button with a similar path".

Comment: by "every button with a similar path" I meant every button with the same path of selectors. i.e: all the read more button has the same selector path across the page and click them all to extend them and access their data. @theDavidBarton